# Resolve Python Module Error To Enable Web Scraping script?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Using stackoverflow for the first time trying to figure out how to scrape Yelp data and having a hard time. Have set up LXML, beautiful soup, requests, PIP, Python and have added these to the path in system variables yet I am still getting the error below when I try to run code below. Any suggestions?

File "test2.py", line 4, in 
    from exceptions import ValueError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

```
from lxml import html  
import json
import requests
from exceptions import ValueError
import re, urllib
import urllib3
import argparse
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import sys
from threading import Thread
import os

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

#[#'https://www.yelp.com/biz/kdb-kitchen-den-bar-long-beach',
yelp_urls =['https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-atlas-room-washington','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-rack-brandon','https://www.yelp.com/biz/payard-p%C3%A2tisserie-and-bistro-new-york-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/maison-giraud-pacific-palisades','https://www.yelp.com/biz/saltbox-san-diego','https://www.yelp.com/biz/carmichaels-chicago-steak-house-chicago','https://www.yelp.com/biz/black-eyed-pea-restaurant-houston-6','https://www.yelp.com/biz/perfecto-mundo-latin-fusion-bistro-commack','https://www.yelp.com/biz/smittys-bbq-boyd','https://www.yelp.com/biz/reston-kabob-reston','https://www.yelp.com/biz/bookmark-cafe-largo','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-tin-angel-pittsburgh','https://www.yelp.com/biz/briantos-original-hoagies-orlando','https://www.yelp.com/biz/freeway-diner-woodbury','https://www.yelp.com/biz/river-gods-cambridge','https://www.yelp.com/biz/golan-kosher-restaurant-north-hollywood-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/city-hall-restaurant-new-york-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/empire-pizza-and-grill-west-chester','https://www.yelp.com/biz/cityzen-washington-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/three-degrees-los-gatos','https://www.yelp.com/biz/applebees-grill-bar-quakertown','https://www.yelp.com/biz/johnny-carinos-covina','https://www.yelp.com/biz/buffet-de-la-gare-hastings-hdsn','https://www.yelp.com/biz/continental-food-management-la-mirada','https://www.yelp.com/biz/elephant-bar-restaurant-peoria','https://www.yelp.com/biz/sullivans-steakhouse-denver','https://www.yelp.com/biz/yucatan-liquid-stand-coppell','https://www.yelp.com/biz/tomato-pie-morristown','https://www.yelp.com/biz/willett-house-port-chester','https://www.yelp.com/biz/thai-corner-san-antonio-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/silkes-american-grill-mesa','https://www.yelp.com/biz/t-mex-cantina-fort-lauderdale-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/casa-oaxaca-washington','https://www.yelp.com/biz/wings-on-wheels-hebron','https://www.yelp.com/biz/siris-thai-french-cuisine-cherry-hill','https://www.yelp.com/biz/nightwood-chicago','https://www.yelp.com/biz/cafe-gallery-burlington','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-hurricane-caf%C3%A9-seattle-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/231-ellsworth-san-mateo','https://www.yelp.com/biz/la-marmite-williston-park','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-river-house-palm-beach-gardens-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/langermanns-baltimore','https://www.yelp.com/biz/del-friscos-grille-phoenix','https://www.yelp.com/biz/carrows-family-restaurant-antioch','https://www.yelp.com/biz/minerva-fine-indian-herndon-va-herndon-5','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-mason-bar-dallas','https://www.yelp.com/biz/la-cote-cafe-and-wine-bar-seattle','https://www.yelp.com/biz/vareli-new-york','https://www.yelp.com/biz/wendys-wixom','https://www.yelp.com/biz/lanterna-tuscan-bistro-nyack','https://www.yelp.com/biz/yo-taco-duxbury','https://www.yelp.com/biz/bombay-palace-new-york','https://www.yelp.com/biz/cafe-buonaros-naperville','https://www.yelp.com/biz/ponti-seafood-grill-seattle-3','https://www.yelp.com/biz/bill-johnsons-big-apple-restaurants-phoenix-5','https://www.yelp.com/biz/by-word-of-mouth-oakland-park','https://www.yelp.com/biz/anna-maries-pizza-and-restaurant-wharton','https://www.yelp.com/biz/dierdorf-and-harts-steakhouse-saint-louis','https://www.yelp.com/biz/wine-5-cafe-las-vegas','https://www.yelp.com/biz/ernies-restaurant-plymouth','https://www.yelp.com/biz/next-door-pizza-and-pub-lees-summit','https://www.yelp.com/biz/lannys-alta-cocina-mexicana-fort-worth','https://www.yelp.com/biz/jalisco-mexican-restaurant-eastlake','https://www.yelp.com/biz/clio-boston','https://www.yelp.com/biz/uncommon-grounds-aliquippa','https://www.yelp.com/biz/uozumi-restaurant-palmdale','https://www.yelp.com/biz/enzos-pizza-matawan','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-pointe-cafe-south-san-francisco','https://www.yelp.com/biz/captains-restaurant-and-seafood-market-florida-city','https://www.yelp.com/biz/le-perigord-new-york-4','https://www.yelp.com/biz/i-love-thai-arlington','https://www.yelp.com/biz/bistro-44-bedford','https://www.yelp.com/biz/ritters-marietta','https://www.yelp.com/biz/rouge-et-blanc-new-york','https://www.yelp.com/biz/assembly-steak-house-and-seafood-grill-englewood-cliffs-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/american-turkish-restaurant-fort-lauderdale','https://www.yelp.com/biz/r-and-r-bar-b-que-and-catering-service-missouri-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/sushi-land-long-beach','https://www.yelp.com/biz/longshots-sports-bar-waretown','https://www.yelp.com/biz/salt-creek-barbeque-glendale-heights','https://www.yelp.com/biz/pizza-market-breese','https://www.yelp.com/biz/john-qs-steakhouse-cleveland','https://www.yelp.com/biz/bistro-n-boca-raton-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/samanthas-restaurant-silver-spring-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/baha-brothers-sandbar-grill-taunton-3','https://www.yelp.com/biz/cafe-cortina-farmington-hills-5','https://www.yelp.com/biz/big-beaver-tavern-troy','https://www.yelp.com/biz/hogans-restaurant-bloomfield-hills','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-copper-monkey-beaverton','https://www.yelp.com/biz/clement-street-bar-and-grill-san-francisco','https://www.yelp.com/biz/pepin-scottsdale','https://www.yelp.com/biz/village-belle-philadelphia','https://www.yelp.com/biz/sweet-woodruff-san-francisco','https://www.yelp.com/biz/siam-marina-tinley-park','https://www.yelp.com/biz/luigis-italian-restaurant-centennial-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/smokin-wills-barbecue-roselle','https://www.yelp.com/biz/voltaire-restaurant-scottsdale','https://www.yelp.com/biz/jus-cookins-restaurant-lakewood-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/pegs-countryside-cafe-hamel','https://www.yelp.com/biz/rays-grill-fulshear','https://www.yelp.com/biz/cafe-zalute-rosemont','https://www.yelp.com/biz/guard-house-inn-gladwyne','https://www.yelp.com/biz/road-runner-grand-canyon-las-vegas-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/garage-restaurant-and-cafe-new-york','https://www.yelp.com/biz/los-tapatios-cedar-hill','https://www.yelp.com/biz/chengdu-46-clifton','https://www.yelp.com/biz/moby-dick-house-of-kabob-fairfax','https://www.yelp.com/biz/natures-food-patch-clearwater','https://www.yelp.com/biz/taco-del-mar-hillsboro-3','https://www.yelp.com/biz/ms-tootsies-rbl-philadelphia','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-big-c-athletic-club-concord','https://www.yelp.com/biz/west-hanover-pizzeria-hanover','https://www.yelp.com/biz/georges-pastaria-houston','https://www.yelp.com/biz/encuentro-oakland-3','https://www.yelp.com/biz/smokys-bbq-eldersburg','https://www.yelp.com/biz/ruby-tuesday-san-antonio','https://www.yelp.com/biz/saladworks-philadelphia-4','https://www.yelp.com/biz/captain-pizza-middleton','https://www.yelp.com/biz/bob-evans-fredericksburg-3','https://www.yelp.com/biz/frittata-clawson','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-sandwich-spot-palm-springs','https://www.yelp.com/biz/freds-mexican-cafe-san-diego-4','https://www.yelp.com/biz/geordies-steak-phoenix-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/five-guys-wayne-5','https://www.yelp.com/biz/zen-sushi-la-crescenta-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-summit-steakhouse-aurora-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/miramar-bistro-highwood','https://www.yelp.com/biz/mick-o-sheas-baltimore','https://www.yelp.com/biz/dennys-houston-30','https://www.yelp.com/biz/carls-jr-henderson-5','https://www.yelp.com/biz/mexican-town-restaurant-detroit','https://www.yelp.com/biz/sushi-roku-las-vegas','https://www.yelp.com/biz/giant-pizza-king-san-diego','https://www.yelp.com/biz/quiznos-brooklyn-6','https://www.yelp.com/biz/taco-bell-glen-ellyn','https://www.yelp.com/biz/las-tortas-locas-marietta','https://www.yelp.com/biz/smith-and-wollensky-las-vegas-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/happy-garden-chinese-brighton','https://www.yelp.com/biz/urban-foodie-feed-store-college-park','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-wolf-oakland','https://www.yelp.com/biz/scuzzis-italian-restaurant-san-antonio-4','https://www.yelp.com/biz/better-gourmet-health-kitchen-staten-island','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-restaurant-and-cafe-warren','https://www.yelp.com/biz/mcdonalds-houston-214','https://www.yelp.com/biz/pyeong-chang-tofu-house-oakland','https://www.yelp.com/biz/maria-rosa-pizzeria-and-family-restaurant-flemington','https://www.yelp.com/biz/legends-sports-bar-and-grill-roseville-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/villa-reale-pizzeria-and-restaurant-pittsburgh','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-terrace-cafe-venice','https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-oval-room-washington-2','https://www.yelp.com/biz/high-point-coal-center','https://www.yelp.com/biz/j-and-s-montebello','https://www.yelp.com/biz/cheers-restaurant-and-bar-fort-lauderdale']

def parse_page(url):
    # url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/frances-san-francisco"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).text
    parser = html.fromstring(response)
    raw_name = parser.xpath("//h1[contains(@class,'page-title')]//text()")
    raw_claimed = parser.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'claim-status_icon--claimed')]/parent::div/text()")
    raw_reviews = parser.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'biz-main-info')]//span[contains(@class,'review-count rating-qualifier')]//text()")
    raw_category  = parser.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"biz-page-header")]//span[@class="category-str-list"]//a/text()')
    hours_table = parser.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'hours-table')]//tr")
    details_table = parser.xpath("//div[@class='short-def-list']//dl")
    raw_map_link = parser.xpath("//a[@class='biz-map-directions']/img/@src")
    raw_phone = parser.xpath(".//span[@class='biz-phone']//text()")
    raw_address = parser.xpath('//div[@class="mapbox-text"]//div[contains(@class,"map-box-address")]//text()')
    raw_wbsite_link = parser.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'biz-website')]/a/@href")
    raw_price_range = parser.xpath("//dd[contains(@class,'price-description')]//text()")
    raw_health_rating = parser.xpath("//dd[contains(@class,'health-score-description')]//text()")
    rating_histogram = parser.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'histogram')]//tr[contains(@class,'histogram_row')]")
    raw_ratings = parser.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'biz-page-header')]//div[contains(@class,'rating')]/@title")
    working_hours = []
    for hours in hours_table:
        raw_day = hours.xpath(".//th//text()")
        raw_timing = hours.xpath("./td//text()")
        day = ''.join(raw_day).strip()
        timing = ''.join(raw_timing).strip()
        working_hours.append({day:timing})
    info = []
    for details in details_table:
        raw_description_key = details.xpath('.//dt//text()')
        raw_description_value = details.xpath('.//dd//text()')
        description_key = ''.join(raw_description_key).strip()
        description_value = ''.join(raw_description_value).strip()
        info.append({description_key:description_value})

    ratings_histogram = [] 
    for ratings in rating_histogram:

        raw_rating_key = ratings.xpath(".//th//text()")
        raw_rating_value = ratings.xpath(".//td[@class='histogram_count']//text()")
        rating_key = ''.join(raw_rating_key).strip()
        rating_value = ''.join(raw_rating_value).strip()
        ratings_histogram.append({rating_key:rating_value})

    name = ''.join(raw_name).strip()
    phone = ''.join(raw_phone).strip()
    address = ' '.join(' '.join(raw_address).split())
    health_rating = ''.join(raw_health_rating).strip()
    price_range = ''.join(raw_price_range).strip()
    claimed_status = ''.join(raw_claimed).strip()
    reviews = ''.join(raw_reviews).strip()
    category = ','.join(raw_category)
    cleaned_ratings = ''.join(raw_ratings).strip()

    if raw_wbsite_link:
        decoded_raw_website_link = urllib.unquote(raw_wbsite_link[0])
        website = re.findall("biz_redir\?url=(.*)&website_link",decoded_raw_website_link)[0]
    else:
        website = ''

    if raw_map_link:
        decoded_map_url =  urllib.unquote(raw_map_link[0])
        map_coordinates = re.findall("center=([+-]?\d+.\d+,[+-]?\d+\.\d+)",decoded_map_url)[0].split(',')
        latitude = map_coordinates[0]
        longitude = map_coordinates[1]
    else:
        latitude = ''
        longitude = ''

    if raw_ratings:
        ratings = re.findall("\d+[.,]?\d+",cleaned_ratings)[0]
    else:
        ratings = 0

    data={'working_hours':working_hours,
        'info':info,
        'ratings_histogram':ratings_histogram,
        'name':name,
        'phone':phone,
        'ratings':ratings,
        'address':address,
        'health_rating':health_rating,
        'price_range':price_range,
        'claimed_status':claimed_status,
        'reviews':reviews,
        'category':category,
        'website':website,
        'latitude':latitude,
        'longitude':longitude,
        'url':url,

    }
    return data

def parse_reviews(url):

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0.'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).text
    parser = html.fromstring(response)
    ratings_zipped = []


    reviews = [x for x in parser.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'main-section')]//div[contains(@class,'review-list')]//div[contains(@class,'review')]//div[contains(@class,'review-content')]")]
    for r in reviews:
        date = r.xpath("./div[contains(@class,'biz-rating')]//span[contains(@class,'rating-qualifier')]/text()")[0].strip()
        rating =  r.xpath("./div[contains(@class,'biz-rating')]//div[contains(@class,'rating-large')]/@title")[0]
        content = r.xpath("./p")[0].text_content()
        ratings_zipped.append([date, rating, content])
    print (len(ratings_zipped))
    return ratings_zipped



def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


def parse_pagination(url):
    print (url)

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    print (response)
    parser = html.fromstring(response.text)
    try:
        results = (int(parser.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'page-of-pages')]//text()")[0].strip().split(' ').pop()))*20
    except IndexError:
        results = 20

    print (results)
    return results



def get_businesses_data(data):
    businesses, failed_searches = [], []
    start_time = time.time()
    result = {}
    for i,url in enumerate(data):
        print ('Starting iteration: ', i)
        result['url']= url
        pagination = parse_pagination(url)
        print ('Pagination: ', pagination)
        info = parse_page(url)
        result['info'] = info

        _reviews = []
        for v in xrange(0,pagination,20):
            paginated_url = result['url'].split('?')[0]  + '?start='+str(v)
            print ('Scraping Reviews: ', paginated_url)
            _reviews += parse_reviews(paginated_url)
            time.sleep(.5)

        result['scraped_reviews'] = _reviews
        result['scraped_reviews_count'] = len(_reviews)

        businesses.append(result)
        print ('Success iteration: ', i)
       # print ('Results: ', result)
        print ('Num of reviews: ', str(len(_reviews)))
        print('')
        print ('Time Elapsed: ', str(time.time() - start_time))

    return businesses


if __name__=="__main__":
    index = 5

    #0
    size = 20
    i = index*20

    chunk = yelp_urls[i:i+size]
    businesses = get_businesses_data(chunk)
    with open ('results/run_3/output_{}.json'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        json.dump(businesses,f)
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from exceptions import ValueError
```

You don't need to do that at all, `ValueError` is part of the built-in exceptions, not to mention the fact that you never use it in your code

Comment: Happy to help @EdwardArmstrong , notice the error already told you pretty much everything I did. Reading the error can really save you a lot of headaches

Comment: Any idea on this error: Parsing the page
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yelp_business_details.py", line 108, in <module>
    with open("scraped_data-%s.json"%(yelp_id),'w') as fp:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'scraped_data-the-bird-washington?osq=Restaurants.json'

Comment: @EdwardArmstrong yeah you can't have a filename with a question mark